# Why isn't the "God of the forge" pantheon available?

Tags: civilization-6

I'm playing Civilization VI: Rise and Fall now. I just got enough faith to start a pantheon and I can't seem to find "God of the forge".

Is there a requirement for this pantheon, or was it removed?

Comment: Were you the first one to establish your pantheon? Pantheon beliefs are first-come, first-serve, IIRC.

Comment: Ah. That makes sense. I might have missed the notification. Could you please post it as the answer so I can accept and close this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pantheon beliefs are first-come, first-serve so it's possible that one of the other civilizations started a pantheon first and picked God of the Forge.

Comment: You can go into the religion tab and see what things have been taken to actually confirm it.